# How to limit only one session per user and block the subsequent login attempt?

Tags: spring, spring-security

The default behavior of concurrency control is to expire the original session. However, I would like to block the second user which is logging in with the same credentials with displaying message "User has already logged in". How can I accomplish this ?

Below is the configuration of spring-security.xml:

```
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll"
        requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/userHasLoggedIn" access="permitAll"
        requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_*" access="permitAll"
        requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/session*" access="permitAll"
        requires-channel="https" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"
        requires-channel="https" />
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/sessionExpired" session-authentication-error-url="/loginAlready">
        <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" expired-url="/userHasLoggedIn" max-sessions="1"/>
    </session-management>
    <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</http>
```

**(Updated)** My final spring security configuration:

```
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll"
            requires-channel="https" />
        <form-login default-target-url="/home" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"
            requires-channel="https" />
        <session-management session-authentication-error-url="/loginFailed">
            <concurrency-control expired-url="/loginFailed" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1"/>
        </session-management>
        <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    </http>
```

Comment: The reason most applications expire the first session is that, with http, it is difficult to know for sure that it is still in use. Think of the case your user's browser is closed accidentally or hangs. Your user may try to reconnect immediately and your app may reject the connection because it thinks the previous session is still ongoing.

Comment: Can it be solved by using session timeout in web.xml ?

Comment: Although you can time out a session, it would not solve the case I mentioned above. The user would have to wait for the session to time out before being able to successfully log in again. You could make the time-out duration small but that would harm users who are logged in to a session and become inactive for that small period. There are workarounds (like sending "heartbeats" in the background) but it can get complicated.

Comment: I am trying to achieve same thing but facing issue mentioned by @Eduardo in case of browser closed/crashed I am not able to login again until session got expired.
So is there any API or setting provided by spring to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is [in the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-concurrent-sessions):

> Often you would prefer to prevent a second login, in which case you
>   can use
>
> ```
> <http>
>   ...
>   <session-management>
>       <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
>   </session-management>
> </http>
> ```
>
> The second login will then be rejected. By “rejected”, we mean that 
>   the user will be sent to the `authentication-failure-url` if
>   form-based login is being used. If the second authentication takes
>   place through another non-interactive mechanism, such as
>   “remember-me”, an “unauthorized” (402) error will be sent to the
>   client. If instead you want to use an error page, you can add the
>   attribute `session-authentication-error-url` to the
>   `session-management` element.

So basically set `error-if-maximum-exceeded` to `"true"` and remove `expired-url` attribute from `<concurrency-control>`.

Comment: It help me too, however I am still looking to destroy session on browser closed/hang.

Comment: @ManojP how would you find out that the browser was closed?

Comment: will this work with cluster of tomcat server as individual tomcat will maintain separate session. does this feature use database.