# Disable multiple session support in Spring Session

Tags: java, spring, spring-session

I would like to use `Spring Session` in an xml-config-based project, but without support for multiple sessions (user-logins) in the same browser window.

Can that be disabled? If yes, how?

Comment: hope it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985862/how-to-limit-only-one-session-per-user-and-block-the-subsequent-login-attempt

Comment: What do you want to disable, only multiple logins but allow multiple sessions with same login? Or do you want to only allow one single session per browser? It is not the same thing...

Comment: I want only one single session per browser. I don't want the ?_s=x mechanism at all for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [`CookieHttpSessionStrategy#setSessionAliasParamName` javadoc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/http/CookieHttpSessionStrategy.java#L260-L269):

> Sets the name of the HTTP parameter that is used to specify the
>   session alias. If the value is null, then only a single session is
>   supported per browser.

So with Spring XML config this translates to:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.session.web.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy">
    <property name="sessionAliasParamName">
        <null/>
    </property>
</bean>
```